# ajax post request to php on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've seen this asked many times and I've tried to implement the solution but it's not working for me. How do you properly make a post ajax request and retrieve the data in php, on the same page?

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST['img_url']); # ALWAYS NULL
?>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/steal/steal.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jquery/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
steal('jquery/dom/fixture').then(function(){

$.fixture("GET /event/{code}", function(original, settings, headers){
    return [200, "success", { "img_url":"http://path/to/img.png" }, {} ]
})

var strObj = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST); ?>;
var str = strObj.q;
var eventCode = str.split('/')[1];
console.log(eventCode);

$.ajax({
  url: "/event/"+eventCode,
  success: function(data) {
     //document.write('<img src="'+data.img_url+'"/>');
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {img_url : data.img_url}
     });
   }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: I had to use $.post in order for this to work. `$.ajax({
  url: "/event/"+eventCode,
  success: function(data) {
     var imgUrl = data.img_url;
     $.post('/tracker.php', 'val='+imgUrl, function (response) {
        $('#trackerImg').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64,"+response);
     });
   }
});`. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I guess this isn't working after all. Does anyone know why the $_POST vars are always empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax post request to php $\_POST vars empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716542/ajax-post-request-to-php-post-vars-empty)