# ajax post request to php $_POST vars empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx

I have a nginx rewrite rule that redirects an img src attribute to a php page. Within this php page I'm trying make a GET request, which on success makes a POST request to the same page, sending the data returned from the GET request as the data. Why is the $_POST data empty in the php script? If I hardcode `$name = "http://path/to/my/img.png"` in the php script the image renders correctly.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
//if(isset($_POST['val'])) {


  // open the file in a binary mode

  $name = $_POST['val']; // ALWAYS EMPTY
  $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

  // send the right headers
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

  // dump the picture and stop the script
  //echo fpassthru($fp);
  header("Location: $name");
  exit;

//}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/steal/steal.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jquery/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
steal('jquery/dom/fixture').then(function(){

$.fixture("GET /event/{code}", function(original, settings, headers){
    return [200, "success", { "img_url":"http://path/to/my/img.png" }, {} ]
})

var strObj = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST); ?>;
var str = strObj.q;
var eventCode = str.split('/')[1];
$.ajax({
  url: "/event/"+eventCode,
  success: function(data) {
     var imgUrl = data.img_url
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'json',
        data: {val:imgUrl},
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log(textStatus);
        }
     });
   }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay hold up. you're trying to have the src of an image point to this php page, inside that php page you're outputting javascript (allegedly for the users browser to run) and then having a POST request sent to the same url with the data they just got in GET?

Comment: This is for email tracking. Basically, the user is to receive an email and upon opening that email the img src attribute makes a request to a uri, which is then rewritten to the php script. The php script receives the $_REQUEST data -- containing some id that is tied to a user, makes a GET request with that id, which on success returns a url. From here the url is used as data for a POST request to the same php page where it will be base64 encoded and returned as the img src attribute. This sounds convoluted to me as well, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you've taken things a few steps beyond what is possible.

When the user hits this image in their email, a request is sent to your server asking for that image. None of that javascript is going to make it back to the user because the `<img>` tag is expecting an image, not an html document. You can tack things on to the outgoing request via something like

```
<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/tracker.php?val=someimage.png">
```

and your script will be able to get `val` out of `$_GET` but you won't be able to make a POST request for this image from inside an email.

All that `$_REQUEST` data you're getting at the top there? That's where you get all your email tracking data from. Everything you can get out of there and `$_GET` is all you're getting.

Afterwards, you need to give them back an image. So heres how you do that.

```
$val = $_GET['val']; // assuming val contains an image

header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('/path/to/your/images/'. $val);
```

Please be super aware that you need to sanity check `$val` to make sure its only containing images that you want to be able to see. A potentially malicious user could see this and put something like `tracker.php?val=/etc/passwd` or something similar and then you've got PHP trying to read your password file. Making sure that images exist and can even be read can be done with the [`is_readable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) function.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually gotten a little further by doing everything in php. I've successfully rendered the image but now the requirement is to render a base64 encoded image, which I'm not sure is possible. `$response = http_get("http://www.google.com", array("timeout"=>1), $info); // act as fixture.
$info['img_url'] = 'http://path/to/my/img.png';
$img_url = $info['img_url'];
$img = file_get_contents($img_url);
$img_data = base64_encode($img); 
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Location: $img_url"); //works
echo "data:image/png;base64,$img_data"; //doesn't work
exit;

Comment: The problem here is that once the html gets to the users inbox, it can no longer be modified. You'll have to echo out the base64 encoded image before the html is rendered and sent to the user. There's no way around this. What most people do with a tracking image is make it a single pixel image lodged somewhere in the email alongside the rest of the emails normal content.

Comment: That's what I figured. The requirement was to use the actual company logo due to increased email being marked as spam with the 1px image. I'm not able to actually test this in an email client yet, will the `header("Content-Type: image/png"); header("Location: $img_url");` portion work within the email client?

Comment: replace `header("Location: $img_url");` with `readfile($img_url);` so that the php page spits out the image.

Comment: So far the image is rendering when I view the html document in my browser, though, I'll have to check it in an email client to verfiy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you happen to know why readfile is so slow? readfile is referencing an external url, is there a better function for loading an external image? `ob_end_clean();
// set image content type
header("Content-Type: image/png");
// output image
readfile($img_url);
exit;`

Comment: readfile is taking forever because its having to download the image into your server and then redisplay the image. the only want to make that faster is to reference the image as it exists on the machine. so instead of `readfile("http://...");` you would change it to `readfile("/var/www/images/image.jpg");`